Thread number quota for grpc client
Ray sets max thread number on grpc client, code link: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/2e4a126deecf84d2930ad772e763e206e2f5f7d2/src/ray/rpc/grpc_client.h#L112-L129
I'm confused why thread number needs to be configured at client side, and whether it makes any effect.
From my understanding:

The argument is made for grpc server. Threads are allocated at server side, by default each grpc request is handled by a different thread, coming out of a threadpool maintained internally; the quota linked in the code caps the max number of thread resource.
While on client side, apart from the polling thread (all sync grpc calls are built upon async one, which bakes an eventloop in a polling thread), I'm not sure why there're other threads necessary, since it leverages HTTP/2 and IO multiplex underlying.


https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/ -> e.g. completion queues.  So at least it is clear gRPC can use more threads, e.g when using streams. (Note: I've seen ClientReadReactor callbacks coming in from multiple threads as well)

Hi @PepijnKramer wow that's careful reading and thanks for the answer! Now I'm clear grpc could have multiple threads, which could be bound to completion queues. Do you happen to know how sync grpc request, or connection, has any relationship with completion queue? For example, I'm sure one cq could serve multiple requests, so in theory one cq is enough to serve all req/resp

I didn't do any in depth investigation ever into gRPC internals. It is just things I did notice when writing/trying to get  a client reactor working. But I kind of remembered seeing this remark on completion queues.
